# Immutable set in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming

I'm looking for a "set" data structure to hold integers in the range 1..10^18. Currently I'm using Data.Set for that.

However, in my case, once the set is built, I won't insert anything on it anymore, I'll just perform lots of "contains" queries.

Is there a data structure in Haskell that optimizes this case? (build once, query from read-only)? I guess the implementation of Data.Set is optimized for fast insertions and retrievals, but I don't care if the insertion is slower, since I'll do it only once.

Comment: So you're wanting something with `O(1)` lookup and you don't care as much for insertion time.  Do you know how many items will be in the collection before you start inserting, or is there a way to figure that out?  You could use a `Vector` instead.

Comment: [`Data.HashSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.5.1/docs/Data-HashSet.html) could be what you seek.

Comment: @bheklilr In principle I could use Data.Set to build a first version of the set, and use this to build final data structure. So the size of the set may be considered known in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.2/docs/Data-IntSet.html<sup>[[link]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.2/docs/Data-IntSet.html)</sup>

Comment: This should really get flagged as link only answer ;)

Comment: @ThreeFx: took me a while to figure out how to best circumvent the automatic "0 characters in body" rejection, as html comments etc. don't work anymore...

Comment: Isn't IntSet limited to 32-bits? My set has 64-bits numbers.

Comment: @Ricbit "Many operations have a worst-case complexity of O(min(n,W)). This means that the operation can become linear in the number of elements with a maximum of W -- the number of bits in an Int (32 or 64)." So `IntSet` is just a `Set` specialized for `Int`s. If these have 64 bits then the `Set` will hold 64 bit numbers.